# Change the order of elements in first axis tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an n dimensional tensor . I want to change the order of elements based on first axis and a given order. For example (1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 5) should give me this result for this matrix:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]     
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]   ==>  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

The order is important for me because I have some tensors and I want all of them to be reordered with the same order. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Provide some code which you tried/are working on so that we can work on it to find a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather):

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    data = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
    idx = [1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 5]
    result = tf.gather(data, idx)
    print(sess.run(result))
```

Output:

```
[[0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1]]
```